# What is this category of circles?

Tags: ct.category-theory

I am working on a problem in Analysis and somehow I arrived to the following category that I suspect is isomorphic to the category of finite dimensional Hilbert spaces. Sorry if my description sounds a bit vague, I know very little about Category Theory.

- Objects are finite collections of oriented circles in the plane. Each circle has an identity map and an associated inversion map in the sense of classical planar geometry.
- Morphisms are a bit more difficult to specify:

Suppose that we have two systems, each of them consisting of just one circle, say $C_{p,r}$ with center $p$ and radius $r$, and $C_{q,s}$ with center $q$ and radius $s$. The circles $C_{p,r}$ and $C_{q,s}$ have associated reflections $R_{p,r}$ and $R_{q,s}$, which are maps defined everywhere on the plane but on $p$ and $q$, respectively. One can show that, for every point $x$ different from $p$ and $q$, we have:

$$R_{p,r}\circ R_{q,s}(x) = R_{q,s}\circ R_{p,r}(x).$$

This allows us to define a morphism $T_{\{(p,r),(q,s)\}}$ between $C_{p,r}$ and $C_{q,s}$ equal to either of the expressions above, but it does not seem possible to set a source and a target for it, i.e., is it an arrow from $C_{p,r}$ to $C_{q,s}$ or vice--versa?

However, note the following: let $\mathcal{C}$ be a "reference circle'' with its own reflection $\mathcal{R}$. Then it seems that the category can be localized or something similar. The maps
$$T_{\{(p,r),(q,s)\}}$$
and
$$T_{\{(p,r),(q,s)\}}\circ\mathcal{R}$$
are now different and we can say that one of them takes the reference circle $\mathcal{C}$ to $C_{p,r}$ and the other one takes $C_{q,s}$ to $\mathcal{C}$. I am not so sure about this last statement.

In this category there is also a dagger $^\dagger$ and an inner product $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathcal{C}$, both induced by the choice of $\mathcal{C}$. The notation $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle_\mathcal{C}$ reminds me of an inner product on the tangent space.

Comment: Your morphisms can have sources and targets - have two morphisms: one with source $C_{p, r}$ and target $C_{q, s}$ and one the other way. The category of sets with bijections as morphisms is a perfectly fine category, and still has sources and targets, because each bijection (in a sense) appears twice. However, it looks to me like the category, if anything, has only one object - the plane - and morphisms that are symmetries of the plane (generated by inversions).

Comment: Are you saying any two inversions commute? Because that's not true.

Comment: In addition to the error pointed out by @darijgrinberg, the question says nothing about morphisms between objects of more than one circle, gives no information about composing morphisms, and gives no idea why the OP thinks this should have anything to do with the category of finite-dimensional Hilbert spaces. I'll vote to close as unclear.